# Log4j 1.2 Bridge update to 2.17.2 RollingFileAppender MaxBackupIndex Problem

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I recently updated my log4j 1.2.13 to log4j 2.17.2 using log4j 1.2 bridge API.

My existing RollingFileAppender configuration is as below:

```
log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%-4t] %c{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n
log4j.appender.app.File=${applicationLogs}/app.log
log4j.appender.app.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.app.MaxFileSize=10KB
log4j.appender.app.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

As per Apache log4j documentation: if logging to a file named `file.log`, when the file size reaches the specified size limit, the contents are archived in a file named `file.log.1` and `file.log` is truncated. When the size limit is reached the second time, `file.log.1` is renamed to `file.log.2`; contents from `file.log` are archived to `file.log.1` and `file.log` is truncated.

But after the library update, the contents are getting archived in serial manner: when the size limit is reached the second time, `file.log.1` is **not getting renamed to** `file.log.2`; instead contents from `file.log` are archived to `file.log.2` and `file.log` is truncated.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a bug in `log4j-1.2-api` (I reported it as [apache/logging-log4j2#1650](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1650)).

**Edit:** The bug was fixed in version `2.21.0`.

**Deprecated workaround:**

You can work around this problem by switching to the Log4j 2.x configuration format (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)) and set `fileIndex="min"` on the `DefaultRolloverStrategy`.

The 2.x equivalent of your 1.x configuration will then look like:

```xml
<RollingFile name="app"
             fileName="${sys:applicationLogs}/app.log"
             filePattern="${sys:applicationLogs}/app.log.%i">
    <PatternLayout charset="UTF-8"
                   pattern="%d %-5p [%-4t] %c{1}.%M(%L) | %m%n"/>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10KB"/>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="min" max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```